# multi-threading -> cholesky factorization error, rospy

Tags: ros, rospy, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I have two callbacks within a class that share the same data in python. Is it possible that these callbacks are altering the data at the same time?

I am getting an error while trying to take the cholesky of a covariance matrix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190050/multi-threading--%3E-cholesky-factorization-error,-rospy/) by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is perfectly possible. Both run in different threads and might therefore write to the same variable while you're reading it. It must not even be both at the same time but if you are reading it outside the callback then the callback might write to it while reading.

Have a look at [this](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) to see how thread safety and locks work in python.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on 2014-08-13**:
This looks perfect! Hopefully this turns out to be the problem.

thanks